# Javascript Validate Password

Tags: javascript

I'm new to java-script I'm learning now php but I'm having an issue with validating my password in the HTML form 
this is my code :

```
<form action="add_user.php" method="post">
    <h3>Name</h3>
    <input name="name" placeholder="Name">
    <h3>Username</h3>
    <input name="username" placeholder="Username">
    <h3>E-mail</h3>
    <input name="email" placeholder="E-mail">
    <h3>Password</h3>
    <input name="password" placeholder="Name" id="password" type="password">
    <h3>Confirm Password</h3>
    <input name="confirm_pass" placeholder="Name" id="confirm_password" type="password">
    <p id="pass_state"></p>
    <input type="submit" value="Create User">
</form>
<script>
    var pass = document.getElementById("pass");
    var conf_pass = document.getElementById("conf_pass");

    function ValidatePass() {
        if (pass.value != conf_pass.value) {
            document.getElementById("pass_state").innerHTML = "Password Does not match"
        }else {
            document.getElementById("pass_state").innerHTML = "Password match"
        }
    }
</script>
```

Can anyone Help me fix it !

Comment: *"I'm having an issue"* - What is the issue? (Other than the fact that your code doesn't call the `ValidatePass()` function.)

Comment: @nnnnnn He just has a few typos in his code. It's pretty easy to see. Code snippet coming up!

Comment: Why do you need the “Password match” message when the user is forwarded to `add_user.php` anyway?

Comment: as I told you ! 
I'm new to the Javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `dpcument.getElementById()`, make sure you pass in a string as the ID as an argument. For `pass`, pass in `"password"` for the first `<input>` and for `"confirm_password"` for the second `<input>`.

```js
//Pass in strings into document.getElementById():
var pass = document.getElementById("password");
var conf_pass = document.getElementById("confirm_password");

function ValidatePass() {
    if (pass.value != conf_pass.value) {
        document.getElementById("pass_state").innerHTML = "Password Does not match"
    }else {
        document.getElementById("pass_state").innerHTML = "Password match"
    }
}

//Now, if we bind the ValidatePass function to onkeypress event of the pass and conf_pass, we will see that the submit button will run ValidatePass correctly!
pass.addEventListener("keypress", ValidatePass);
conf_pass.addEventListener("keypress", ValidatePass);
```

```html
<form action="add_user.php" method="post">
    <h3>Name</h3>
    <input name="name" placeholder="Name">
    <h3>Username</h3>
    <input name="username" placeholder="Username">
    <h3>E-mail</h3>
    <input name="email" placeholder="E-mail">
    <h3>Password</h3>
    <input name="password" placeholder="Name" id="password" type="password">
    <h3>Confirm Password</h3>
    <input name="confirm_pass" placeholder="Name" id="confirm_password" type="password">
    <p id="pass_state"></p>
    <input type="submit" value="Create User">
</form>
```

Comment: can I do it without clicking on the submit button, instead I wish if it pops up while I'm writing

Comment: You can call the `ValidatePass()` whenever you want. I'll make the above code snippet bind to the `onchange` event of `pass` and `conf_pass` instead to demonstrate.

Comment: Thank you So Much !!
Really appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

Change the following:

```
var pass = document.getElementById(pass);
var conf_pass = document.getElementById(conf_pass);
```

By:

```
var pass = document.getElementById('password');
var conf_pass = document.getElementById('confirm_password');
```

Answer (score 0):

ValidatePass() is never being called. Not sure if your code is incomplete, but I dont see anything with the ID "pass", so getting an element with an id that doesnt exist is useless.